# Build multiple projects

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm exploring the Jenkins world to see if it can fit my needs for this case.
I need to build two git repositories (backend and frontend). For the backend, I would need:

- Choose the branch we want to build from a list
- Checkout the branch and build Docker image using the Dockerfile
- push to ECR
- release to a specific Kubernetes deployment

After backend build, we have to build the frontend by doing:

- Choose the branch we want to build from a list
- Checkout the branch and run npm script to build
- deploy to S3 folder

Build of the project should be triggered only manually, by the project owner (who is not a developer )

Is Jenkins the right way to go? And if yes, could you point me to how you would do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely implement what you need with Jenkins. There are different ways to implement each step. But here are some things you can consider using.

- For Branch listing, you can consider using a plugin like [List Git
  Branches Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/list-git-branches-parameter-plugin)
- For Docker image Building and pushing you can use Jenkins [Docker Steps.](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/)
- For K8S stuff you can probably use a Shell script or can use something like [Kubecli](https://plugins.jenkins.io/kubernetes-cli/)
- For S3 stuff you can use [S3 Publisher Plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/s3/).